# Oracle SQL dynamic Query with ANDs and ORs more performant

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, dynamic, correlated-subquery

Is there a better query to solve this problem ?

1 Car has many Types.

I want something like this: (ps this is incorrect, i know)

```
select * from car join type on car.id = type.id_car 
where type = 'SUV' 
and type = '4x4' 
and (type = 'blue' or type = 'red') 
and type = 'US' 
and (type = 'Manual' or type = 'Automatic' or 'SemiAutomatic') 
and type = 'diesel' and so on.
```

My solution is:

```
select * from car 
where numberOfANDType = (select count(1) from Type where car.id = type.id_car and type in ('suv', '4x4', 'us', 'diesel')) 
and exists (select 1 from type where car.id = type.id_car and type in ('blue', 'red'))
and exists (select 1 from type where car.id = type.id_car and type in ('manual', 'automatic' or 'SemiAutomatic');
```

And so on.

ps: I know the number of conditions used with AND
ps2: these conditions are dynamic.

Anywayz: i have for each Type a GROUP Column, and for the Types used in groups of OR i have the same value in this column. SUV has GROUP = 1, blue has GROUP = 2, red has GROUP = 2 and so on.
So I make a query on the TYPE Column and the count on the group, to see if all groups are covered.

```
Select id from car join type on .. where type in ('SUV', 'blue', 'red') group by id having count(distinct group) > 2;
```

Thanks.

**ps3: thanks to all who downvoted this question, you are very kind.**

Comment: Have you used explain plan to see if this query is not good? If im not mistaken, when you use exists the Oracle will use your type FK that point to car PK.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve - do you want to return all cars that have all of these types, all cars that have all these types but nothing else, all cars that have some of these types but nothing else, or what?

Comment: all cars that have all AND types and at least one from the groups of OR. you can have any number of AND types or groups of OR and inside those groups of OR you can have any number of types.

Comment: is a car filter like [here](http://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?isSearchRequest=false&editSearch=&lang=en&export=ALSO_EXPORT&sortOption.sortOrder=ASCENDING&damageUnrepaired=ALSO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED&sortOption.sortBy=searchNetGrossPrice&scopeId=C&makeModelVariant1.makeId=&maxPrice=&minFirstRegistrationDate=&maxMileage=&fuels=&ambitCountry=&zipcode=). However, the design is bad.

Comment: No: there you have different columns (one for color, one for traction, one for transmission, and so on), here is the problem that is the same column.

Comment: yes, YOU have a bad design :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment to Cosmin's answer, this should work:

```
select car.id 
from car 
join type on car.id = type.id_car 
where type.type in 
('SUV','4x4','blue','red','US','Manual','Automatic','SemiAutomatic','diesel')
group by car.id
having count(distinct type.group)=6
```

Comment: it doesn't work. because the types from the OR groups can increase the count so that it won't cover the single types with AND.

Comment: @CosminVacariou: You said that each of the `or` clauses is for a single type.group value - eg. colours are all group 2. This having clause is on **distinct** values of type.group - so no matter how many colours are specified/selected, the count will only be incremented by 1, no matter how many of the matching colours are selected.

Comment: yep, but your IN is not based on the group column. if it's on the group it's ok :)

Comment: @CosminVacariou: The `in` condition needs to be on the type.type, not the type.group - what if there was a car that met all the other criteria but was only available in green, not red or blue?

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way of solving this would be to be specific about the types and create columns for these:

```
select * from car 
where type = 'SUV' 
and drive_type = '4x4' 
and (colour = 'blue' or colour = 'red') 
and origin = 'US' 
and (transmission = 'Manual' or transmission = 'Automatic') 
and fuel_type = 'diesel'
```

Then you can use indexes to improve the performance of the query.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
select car.* 
from car INNER JOIN (
                     select id, count(*) countMatches
                     from car INNER JOIN type on car.id = type.id_car
                     where type in ('suv', '4x4', 'us', 'diesel','blue', 
                                    'red','manual', 'automatic')
                     group by id
                     having count(*) = 6
                    ) matches ON car.id = matches.id
```

Comment: > 5 still isn't correct. cuz you can have 5 from a single group of 5 ORed items.

Comment: @aF: Doh, thanks, updated. @ Cosmin: Based on the information you provided, this should do what you want. Your question doesn't mention anything about groups, nor does it describe the data structure. If you want a definite answer, you should provide all the relevant information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from car c1 where c1.id in
(
  select c.id from car c
  inner join Type t on c.id = t.id_car and c.type in ('suv', '4x4', 'us', 'diesel', 'blue', 'red', 'manual', 'automatic')
  group by c.id
  having count(distinct *) > 5
)
```

Comment: ps you can't use distinct with *

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad design.

Every group value shoud go into a new column.

So the type table should be:

```
id_car color transmission fuel origin_country etc
1      blue  automatic    gas  UK
....
```

The query would be:

```
select * 
from car join type on (car.id = type.id_car)
where color in ('red', 'blue')
and transmision in ('automatic')
and country in ('US')
etc.
```

Comment: yeah, but this isn't the case.

Comment: my example isn't a good one. the real design is ok in my app.

Comment: it's an ipothetical case? Ok, in this situation you can retain the ideea. this design is an weak EAV an will cause you problems :)